# Unable to locate framework.dir in sencha

Tags: extjs, command

I have installed sencha cmd 4.0.4.84. But when i tried to create an App it is showing  Unalble to locate framework.dir property from sencha config.Ensure the command was executed from a valid framework direcotry.Non framework directory

Answer (score 5):

It is exactly what it says: you are most likely running `sencha` from a wrong directory.

```
cd /where/you/extracted/ext-4.2.1
sencha generate app MyApp /where/you/want/myapp
```

For more details watch: [Creating Workspace and Applications](http://extjs.eu/videos/) video.

Comment: Thank you, I donot understand in an asp.net application with extjs what is the need of installing sencha command.

Comment: Although I do not use Microsoft products so I don't have my own experience, [asp.net](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET) is a server side library/framework and Ext JS is a client side library. Hence, they operate more or less independently - of course the server side (asp.net) has to process requests from the client (Ext JS) and respond accordingly.

Comment: For that we donot need to install extjs through sencha command. We just have to refer extjs and extcss. And if it is a mvc structure we need we need to create a structure of app inside the application that has controller, view seperated.

Comment: As of now, you need to run this from the sencha touch folder

`C:\Users\xyz\Downloads\sencha-touch-2.4.2-commercial\touch-2.4.2>sencha generate app MyApp D:\myapp`

Answer (score 2):

I  made a big mistake- i was running from sencha command root. But it has to be running from 
Extjs  version root.  we have to create a worklocation inside it. their will extjs folder and from their we need run the command to create the App. Now it is working perfectly

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to take a look at the cmd tools and [workspaces](https://docs.sencha.com/cmd/guides/workspaces.html).

A little more specifically take a look at the [framework locations](https://docs.sencha.com/cmd/guides/workspaces.html#workspaces_-_framework_locations) section of the page.

Comment: It's great to add links to resources, but it's much more helpful to include the relevant portions in your answer in case the links break in the future.

Answer (score 1):

It's better to go to the SDK folder just mention the SDK path in your command while generating the app:

```
sencha -sdk <YOUR SDK PATH> generate app <APP NAME> <PATH TO GENERATE APP>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Before creating any sencha app.
Understand 2 things.
1. Sencha CMD
2.Extjs framework.
Both are different.

Coming to point:.
1. Download the latest extjs framework.
2.Use the below command
sencha -sdk=path/to/ext generate app MyAPP path/to/worspace/of/MyApp

This will solve the above issue asked in question.
Danke,
Rahul
```